# Can receive KeyEvent after onDestroy called about Android Activity? Why mapLayout is null?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

`mapLayout` is init at `onCreate` and release at `onDestroy`. Why `mapLayout` is `null` when `onNewIntent` and `dispatchKeyEvent`?

---

`onNewIntent` have `NullPointException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void MapLayout.clearFocusedOverlay()' on a null object reference
at com.xxx.activity.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:486)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2438)
```

---

This is stackTrace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean MapLayout.hasFocusedOverlay()' on a null object reference
        at com.xxx.activity.MainActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(MainActivity.java:794)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2389)
        at ...
```

---

**This is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static MapLayout mapLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
     mapLayout = (MapLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_container);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    mapLayout.clearFocusedOverlay()
  }
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mapLayout = null;
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent: "+event);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
          && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (mapLayout.hasFocusedOverlay()) {
                mapLayout.clearFocusedOverlay();
                mapLayout.mapView.invalidate();
        } else {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
    ***private static MapLayout mapLayout;***
When 'MainActivity' have more than one instance. If one instance of 'MainActivity' destroy, the 'mapLayout' become to 'null'.

So when other instance of 'MainActivity' use 'mapLayout' will cause NullPointException.